# Writing Data In Neo4J Causal Clustering Implementation

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j, cluster-analysis, graph-databases

In a Neo4J Causal Clustering, implemented using 3 AWS EC2 Instances, should the data be written only to Leader Node or can it be written to any Follower Nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Data should always be written to a [core server](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/introduction/#causal-clustering-core-servers), these writes must be acknowledged by a majority of core servers.
Reads can be from any the read replicas.
Using [bookmarks](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/when-to-use-bookmarks/), you are able to "read your own writes", thus making sure of showing consistent data.